# Get the content on the command line with an external promgram

Tags: linux, bash

I would like to write a small program which will analyize my current input on the command line and generate some suggesstions like those search engines do.

The problems is how can an external program get the content on command line? For example

```
# an external program started and got passed in the PID of the shell below.
# the user typed something in the shell like this...

<PROMPT> $ echo "grab this command"

# the external program now get 'echo "grab this command"' 
# and ideally the this could be done in realtime.
```

More over, can I just modify the content of current command line?

**EDIT**

bash uses libreadline to manage the command line, but still I can not imagine how to make use of this.

Comment: I've considered grabbing the stdin of that shell (some pts device), however in this way I have to parse all sort of input (including normal input, escape sequence...). Kind of troublesome.

Comment: To be sure , if you type `echo jack`, your script/program should give you `your command should print "jack" at the stdout` huh?

Comment: @sjsam yeah kind of like that. but the problem is how can an external program get to know that I just typed `echo jack`. Also I have to consider that the user could type more complicated command in an non linear manner by using Ctrl-A, Ctrl-E ...

Comment: @jack : Worth adding above information to the question. If it just a text command, passing them in positional parameters would do, but in your i guess it's bit complicated than that I guess..

Comment: @sjsam thanks for the advice. Like you said it's a little bit complicated for the reason that I what the external programe to be transparent.

Comment: I can see [tag:expect] being used for this, but your requirements are utterly unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write your own shell wrapper using c. Open bash in a process using `popen` and use `fgetc` and `fputc` to write the data to the process and the output file.

A quick dirty hack could look like this (bash isn't started in interactive mode, but otherwise should work fine. --> no prompt):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>


pid_t pid;

void kill_ch(int sig) {
        kill(pid, SIGKILL);
}

/**
 * 
 */
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
        int b;
        FILE *cmd = NULL;
        FILE *log = NULL;

        signal(SIGALRM, (void (*)(int))kill_ch);

        cmd = popen("/bin/bash -s", "r+");
        if (cmd == NULL) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Error: Failed to open process");
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        setvbuf(cmd, NULL, _IOLBF, 0);

        log = fopen("out.txt", "a");
        if (log == NULL) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Error: Failed to open logfile");
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        setvbuf(log, NULL, _IONBF, 0);

        pid = fork();

        if (pid != 0)
                goto EXEC_WRITE;
        else
                goto EXEC_READ;


EXEC_READ:
        while (1) {
                b = fgetc(stdin);
                if (b != EOF) {
                        fputc((char) b, cmd);
                        fputc((char) b, log);
                }
        }

EXEC_WRITE:
        while (1) {
                b = fgetc(cmd);
                if (b == EOF) {
                        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
                }
                fputc(b, stdout);
                fputc(b, log);
        }

        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the program. I finally found that to achive my goal I need to have a pseudo terminal, which is basicly what your program is doing...

Answer (score 0):

I might not fully understand your question but I think you'd basically have two options.

The first option would be to explicitly call your "magic" program by prefixing your call with it like so

```
<PROMPT> $ magic echo "grab this command"
(magic analyzes $* and says...)
Your input would print "grab this command" to stdout
<PROMPT> $
```

In this case the arguments to "magic" would be handled as positional parameters ($*, $1 ...)

The second option would be to wrap an interpreter-like something around your typing. E.g. the Python interpreter does so if called without arguments. You start the interpreter, which will basically read anything you type (stdin) in an endless loop, interpret it, and produce some output (typically on stdout).

```
<PROMPT> $ magic
<MAGIC_PROMPT> $ echo "grab this command"
(your magic interpreter processes the input and says...)
Your input would print "grab this command" to stdout
<MAGIC_PROMPT> $
```

Comment: thanks for the reply and sorry I didn't make myself clear.  I've updated the question.

Comment: Ah, ok, so you want to intercept the stdin of another process? Well, sure this is far more complicated. Given you have the proper permissions for the tty you'd still have to write a shell-like interpreter which can process that input. The "sudosh" command might be an example for what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: That brought me to the idea of launching the shell via a tiny c program, which pipes all in and output to the shell but also records it in a logfile. That actually shouldn't be so troublesome.

Comment: Well that's pretty much exactly what sudosh is doing ;)